# Qual a diferença entre estes 2 códigos PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando PHP e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida: qual seria a diferença entre os seguintes códigos:

```
<?php
class ClasseTeste
{
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = 'root';
    protected $db_name = 'bd_nome';

    public function hello()
    {
        echo $this->db_host;
    }
}
```

E este:

```
<?php
class ClasseTeste
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_host = 'localhost';
        $this->db_user = 'root';
        $this->db_pass = 'root';
        $this->db_name = 'bd_nome';

        /**
         * Gostaria de saber se eu poderia tambem definir o tipo dos campos dentro da funcao __construct(). Dessa maneira:
         *
         * private $this->db_host = 'localhost';
         * private $this->db_user = 'root';
         * private $this->db_pass = 'root';
         * private $this->db_name = 'db_name';
         */
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        echo $this->db_host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 5):

O primeiro código define os atributos de forma explícita como membros da classe e a sua visibilidade também garantida (`protected`) todos eles são acessíveis dentro da classe e suas descendentes como o esperado.

Já o segundo define o construtor como `protected`, ou seja, ele não  pode ser chamado diretamente, nesse caso seria necessário um método estático e público que chamasse o construtor e ao final retornasse objeto desejado. Essa mecanica lembra um pouco o [padrão singleton](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton)

O segundo código no construtor são definidos membros de classe de forma dinâmica que ao primeiro olhar tem o resultado do primeiro código mas não é assim pois os atributos criados dessa forma tem sua visibilidade como public, ou seja, eles são acessíveis por qualquer um e isso viola o encapsulamento.

O que é possível fazer no segundo código e não primeiro.

```
//nesse exemplo mudei o construtor para public para teste
$obj = new ClasseTeste();
echo $obj->db_pass .' - '. $obj->db_user;
```

Answer (score 3):

A única diferença funcional é definir se é `public` ou `protected`. O resto é só mesmo questão organizacional. Tem pessoas que preferem apenas iniciar a variável fora da função e definir os valores na função `__construct`. Mas não faz diferença.

> Gostaria de saber se eu poderia tambem definir o tipo dos campos dentro da funcao __construct(). Dessa maneira:
>
> ```
>     private $this->db_host = 'localhost';
>     private $this->db_user = 'root';
> ```

Não, nesse caso teria que ser fora da função.

*Obs.: A função `__construct` deve ser `public` e não é obrigatório declarar antes, pode ser criado dentro dela.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro código trabalha da seguinte forma:

Tem-se um classe `ClasseTeste` com `4` atributos protegidos, atributos estes referentes ao acesso a um banco e função publica que quando chamada imprime o atributo `db_host`.

O segundo código trabalha da seguinte forma:
Quando a classe esta sendo instanciada ela atribui as `strings` a cada atributo e função publica que quando chamada imprime o atributo `db_host`.
Funciona com ressalvas, não é possível definir o esteriótipo (protect, private, public).

```
<?php
class ClasseTeste
{
 protected $db_host;
    protected $db_user;
    protected $db_pass;
    protected $db_name;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_host = 'localhost';
        $this->db_user = 'root';
        $this->db_pass = 'root';
        $this->db_name = 'bd_nome';
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        echo $this->db_host;
    }
}
$objeto = new ClasseTeste();
$objeto->hello();
?>
```

Comment: Então se eu for usar a função __construct(), eu preciso declarar a variável fora do construtor, e definir o valor dela dentro do __construct()? A função real do __construct() então é, no momento que a classe é instanciada atribuir um valor, mas apenas isso? Correto?

Comment: Não funciona porquê? Não tenho aqui como testar isso, mas não vejo razão para não funcionar...

Comment: `__construct` é o construtor da classe, você não o chama explicitamente mas sim quando você instancia um ubjeto da classe como fiz no meu exemplo.

Comment: Não foi definido os atributos do objeto, atributos estes que estavam sendo atribuidos dentro do construtor

Comment: Correção funciona porem não é possível definir o esteriótipo (protect, private, public) será atribuido o padrão

Comment: era o que me parecia, não tens é o scope definido como protected. mas erro não dá :)

Comment: Mas é uma má prática